# PHP/HTML/JS: External file manager

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload, file-manager

I feel like i am asking something easy but i'm running in circles.

I am creating a form with various fields and i'd like to add a file field with an external file manager (***first problem***: which one? i'm looking into **pydio** but it seems overkill for the needs).
Here is the dumb question: **How do i integrate it in the form?**
I'm quite sure it's an AJAX problem but i have no idea on how to integrate it. I assume i need to call some function onClick() to open the filemanager and there should be some callback to get/set the value on the form.

Any hint&code is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this file manager with some success in the past.

http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you the advice to have a look to the Filemanager :
https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager

For an online demo http://fm.linea21.com

On the wiki pages, we have sample code of what you are trying to do :

- https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/How-to-use-the-filemanager-with-colorbox-%3F
- https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/How-to-use-the-filemanager-from-a-simple-textfield-%3F

Answer (score 0):

I advice the https://github.com/OpusCapita/filemanager

Its a young project but looks promising.